# Opacity animation for svg path

Tags: css, svg

Trying to learn svg / css animations and i don't understand why `path` doesn't have animation to `opacity: 0` on hover even though rest of the elements are animating.

Also I don't understand why each circle is cut by 1-2px near top during the animation. Can someone explain this black magic to me?

Edit for #2 question: Issue only related to chrome, so i guess it could be something with rendering.

Thanks in advance

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqMpRz)

```css
svg:hover{
    animation: initopacity .4s linear;
}

svg:hover .circle{
animation: opacity 2s linear;
      animation-delay: .4s;
}

svg:hover .circle1{
animation: opacity 1s linear;
      animation-delay: .4s;
}

svg:hover .circle2{
animation: opacity 4s linear;
      animation-delay: .4s;
}
svg:hover .line{
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;   
  animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
  
}
@keyframes initopacity {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes opacity {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes dash {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1000;}
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" id="logo" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
  <g>
    <circle class="circle2" cx="2.5" cy="25" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle1" cx="2.5" cy="45" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle" cx="2.5" cy="65" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <!-- col-2 -->
    <circle class="circle" cx="20%" cy="15%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle1" cx="20%" cy="35%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle" cx="20%" cy="55%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle2" cx="20%" cy="75%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <!-- col-3 -->
    <circle class="circle" cx="37.5%" cy="5%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle1" cx="37.5%" cy="25%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle" cx="37.5%" cy="45%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle2" cx="37.5%" cy="65%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle" cx="37.5%" cy="85%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <!-- col-4 -->
    <circle class="circle" cx="55%" cy="15%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle1" cx="55%" cy="35%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle2" cx="55%" cy="55%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle" cx="55%" cy="75%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <!-- col-5 -->
  
    <circle class="circle1" cx="72.5%" cy="25%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle" cx="72.5%" cy="45%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
    <circle class="circle2" cx="72.5%" cy="65%" r="2.5" fill="#00c99a"/>
  </g>
  <!-- lines | starting from center -->
  <path class="line" d="M 37.5 45 L 20 55 L 20 35 L 37.5 25  L 55 35 L 55 55 L 37.5 65" stroke="#00c99a" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke-width="1.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: They are not cut for me and are displaying properly. (I tried with Safari on macOS and Chrome on Android.) What browser/image viewer have you tried?

Comment: Kinda hard to see at first but once you see it, you always see it. Easier to notice when you zoom the browser. It could be due to monitor pixel density maybe, since they are pretty small i guess? E. tried so far only on latest chrome for desktop.

Comment: I tried zooming on the image as well, it's still looking fine.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't happen on mozilla / opera so i guess it's related to chrome oh well.

Comment: if you remove 'fill' from path, you get a black fill that does fade out, however the filled area just appears on fade in!

Comment: Indeed, though would rather not have that fill :\. So actually that would need to be stroke that has to be animated.